# How to get vendor and productId of joystick device with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, joystick

Is there any way to get the vendor and productId of a joystick device with the browser? I am saving in database the joystick configuration, the problem is that in Chrome and Firefox I get diferents IDs, even though the joystick is the same. My aim is to save vendor and productId in database instead the string that is returned in the ID variable that can change with the browser. In both cases is possible to parse the string and get it, but I would like to know if there is a way to access to this variables and not doing it parsing the string.

Example ID in Chrome:
`Thrustmaster T.Flight Hotas X (Vendor: 044f Product: b108)`

Example ID in Firefox:
`044f-b108-Thrustmaster T.Flight Hotas X`

Comment: What code did you run to get those IDs?